# Lebesgue measure of a parallelepiped

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, volume

Suppose we have $n$ linearly independent vectors $\mathbf{x}_1$, $\cdots$, $\mathbf{x}_n$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $\mathbf{X}$ be the $n \times n$ matrix with column $k$ given by $\mathbf{x}_k$, $k = 1, \cdots, n$. I know that the volume of the parallelepiped defined by the set
$$
E = \{\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n: \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{X}\theta \text{ for some $\theta \in [0,1]^n$}\} 
$$ 
is given by $|\det \mathbf{X}|$, the absolute value of the determinant of $\mathbf{X}$.

How can I show that  the Lebesgue measure of $E$ is also equal to $|\det \mathbf{X}|$?

Comment: This isn't really an answer, per se, but the "volume" of a simple geometric feature coincides with its Lebesgue measure.

Comment: There is a full proof in chapter 3 of the book *Lebesgue Integration on Euclidean Space* by Frank Jones. Actually I think it *is* chapter 3.  The idea is to decompose the linear map into maps for which the volume distortion is easier to see.

Comment: @Math1000 Yes I'm trying to prove that fact